# Every continuous function $f:X\times Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the uniform limit of functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $X$, $Y$ metric compact spaces. Prove that every continuous function $f:X\times Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the uniform limit of functions of the form $\varphi (x,y):f_{1}(x)g_{1}(y)+f_{2}(x)g_{2}(y)+\dots+f_{n}(x)g_{n}(y)$ with $f_{i}\in C^0(X)$ and $g_{i}\in C^0(Y)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

My idea was, to make a prove like theorem of Weierstrass for approximation, because, this problem is general, i mean, this is not just for a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, this is for a compact product not necessary subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, but i really don´t find how can i use that prove or something similar, i´ve tried to approximate each $f_{i}$ and $g_{i}$ with a polynomial but again i´ve got nothing from that, can anybody help me?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You should appeal to the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem.

Comment: Look at the version in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis